# Stored procedure to return nvarchar (userId)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure to return a `userID` when a `token` and `tokenType` are received.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UserTokens_Insert]
(
     @userId nvarchar(128) OUT
     ,@tokenType int
     ,@token uniqueidentifier
)
AS
    /*    Execution example
      proc I'm working on...

      DECLARE @userId nvarchar(128)
      DECLARE @tokenType INT
      DECLARE @token uniqueidentifier

     '1415926535897932384626433832795',
     '2',
     '84384121-cac4-41f7-9bb9-8983b8c3ebb8'

     execute [dbo].[UserTokens_Insert] @userId, @tokenType, @token
   */
BEGIN
    SELECT [userId]
    FROM [dbo].[UserTokens]
    WHERE [UserId] = @userId 
      AND [TokenType] = @tokenType 
      AND [Token] = @token



EXECUTE dbo.UserToken_Insert @tokenType, @token, @userId out
```

It errors on the out in the last line. I am using the same thing on other procedures without a problem.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Probably just typos - but **(1)** your procedure is missing an `END`, and **(2)** the procedure is called `[UserTokens_Insert]`, but the execution calls `[UserToken_Insert]` (without the `s` on the `Tokens`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure takes the arguments in a different order than the order you're passing them in your EXECUTE call.

```
@userId, @tokenType, @token
@tokenType, @token, @userId
```